# JS - Importing a single class using Import

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why I'm unable to import a specific class - I'm clearing misunderstanding something fundamental with module imports.

So say I have a index.js file called 'MyModule':

```
'use strict';

const One = require('./One.js');
const Two = require('./Two.js');
const Three = require('./Three.js');;

module.exports = {
  One,
  Two,
  Three
};
```

And say `One.js` looks roughly like:

```
'use strict';

class One {
   constructor(...) { ... }
   ...
}

module.exports = One;
```

When I go to use that module in my code, I'm currently doing:

```
const myMod = require('MyModule');

// Then I use it like so:

const something = new myMod.One(...)
```

This works fine, however why am I not allowed to do:

```
import { One } from require('MyModule')
```

In addition to why that doesn't work, is it beneficial to only import what I need to use?

Your explanations appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't import _and_ require. Do one or the other: `import { One } from 'MyModule'`

Comment: I tried that, but get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can import by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
import { One } from 'MyModule' // This is only allowed within modules not on the main program
```

OR

```js
const { One } = require('MyModule');
```

Comment: The second option works - `const { One } = require('MyModule');` but the first gives me `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: That's actually normal: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field